# Can I update the collection that Parallel.For is using?

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel.for

I have a situation in which I am running some tasks that take a few seconds to minutes each. I also have the possibility that more data gets added that needs to be added to the already running Parallel loop. Is it possible to update the current collection that the Parallel.For is using and have it continue to iterate over this until there are no more objects to retrieve? 
Here's some example code showing my problem:

```
[Test]
public void DoesParallelForGetNewEntriesInLoop()
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
    ConcurrentBag<string> bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    int i = 0;
    // write to dictionary every 10ms simulating new additions
    Timer t = new Timer(callback =>
    {
        dict.TryAdd(i++, "Value" + i);
    }, dict, 0, 10);
    // Add initial values
    dict.TryAdd(i++, "Value" + i);
    dict.TryAdd(i++, "Value" + i);
    dict.TryAdd(i++, "Value" + i);

    Parallel.For(0, dict.Count, (a, state) =>
    {
        string val = string.Empty;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(a, out val))
        {
            bag.Add(val + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        if (i++ == 50)
            state.Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

    });
    foreach (var item in bag)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("parallelWrite.txt", item);
    }            
}
```

When I run this the result I get is simply:

```
Value2
Value1
Value3
Value4
```

Is there a better approach to doing what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `BlockingCollection` and calling `GetConsumingEnumerable()` in your `Parallel.ForEach`

```
BlockingCollection<string> collection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), (x) => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

You can add stuff to the collection using BlockingCollection's `Add()` method.

There is technically "double locking" going on since Parallel.ForEach locks the collection when it takes chunks of items from the enumerable to process and BlockingCollection was built to support multiple consumers so it also implements locking.  If this becomes a performance concern (it very well could) then you can implement your own partitioner for your BlockingCollection since Parallel.ForEach has overloads that accept OrderablePartitioner and Partitioner.  There is a very good article that describes how here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I will try it out and mark this as the answer if it works :)

Comment: I ended up using a little bit different approach, but this helped get me on the right track.

Comment: Don't pass the `BlockingCollection<T>` directly, because it might deadlock in some scenarios. Create a partitioner: `Partitioner.Create(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)` and pass this to the `Parallel.ForEach` instead of the `collection`. It is important that the `Parallel.ForEach` enumerates the collection one item at a time, which is not what the `Parallel.ForEach` does by default.

Answer (score 0):

The from and to parameters in the `Parallel.For`gets computed only once before the loop starts.
Use the `Parallel.ForEach` to iterate over new items.
I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but a better approach might be to put new data in a stack/queue and periodically pop out the data and handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the information about Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach seems to be a bit better, but it seems to get out of the loop before all 50 entries are added (it never gets to the state.Stop())